# lammps input command is not running

Tags: command-line, 18.04, virtualbox, input

I have installed Lammps executeable version for Linux Ubuntu 18.04.2.
Eveything installed perfectly but an error occurs in input commands as following:

```
rashid@rashid-VirtualBox:~$ lmp_daily -in in.lj
ERROR on proc 0: Cannot open input script in.lj (src/lammps.cpp:414)
Last command: (unknown)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 0 in communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
with errorcode 1.
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, it's because the `in.lj` file is not present in the current directory.

You have three possible courses of action:

1. `cd` to a directory containing `in.lj`
2. Copy `in.lj` from wherever it is to the current directory.
3. Specify a full or relative path to an existing `in.lj`, e.g. `lmp_daily -in /home/rashid/other/directory/in.lj`.

Pick one.

Comment: yes it is in.lj command don't exist, but how to do. i am beginner i have installed following tutorials, please give me step by step or you can do using teamviewer i will be very much thanksful to you